# PdfBox 2.0.3 NullPointerException at Font encoding on linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts, pdfbox

I'm currently facing an issue on linux using the Apache PdfBox 2.0.3.

You can see from the code snippet and the exception bellow. The thing I try to do is simply set the Font and then write on a page. Unfortunatelly it's unsuccessful on our linux test and live environment using Tomcat 7 and Java 7 on Ubuntu. On my Windows development machine everything works smoothly.

I already tried to use the built in helvetica and currier fonts, the ttf you see in the snippet is downloaded from google fonts.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The code snippet i'm using:

```
PDPage page = detailsDocument.getPage(0);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(detailsDocument, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
        File fontFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf").getFile());
        PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, fontFile, Encoding.getInstance(COSName.STANDARD_ENCODING));

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont( font, 22 );
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(57, 495);
        contentStream.showText( collection.getDocument().getIndication().getName() + " - " + collection.getDocument().getTitle() );
        contentStream.endText();
```

The exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:311)
    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:414)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.generators.PdfGenerator.addOrderDetailsPage(PdfGenerator.java:361)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.generators.PdfGenerator.generatePdf(PdfGenerator.java:68)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.generators.PdfGenerator.generatePdfToOMR(PdfGenerator.java:268)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.generators.PdfGenerator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fcaef06.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.generators.PdfGenerator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$55740b22.generatePdfToOMR(<generated>)
    hu.jacsomedia.tms.webapp.pdfbuilder.controller.PdfGeneratorController.generate(PdfGeneratorController.java:139)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

Comment: PDFont.java:311 would throw NPE only if the "text" parameter is null. Which can't be according to the code you posted. So either I'm wrong, or your code isn't the one that was called, or it isn't 2.0.3, or you have several different versions in your classpath.

Comment: Try `COSName.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING` instead of `COSName.STANDARD_ENCODING`. Furthermore, using `getFile` on a resource always is a gamble as the resource may be inside an archive and, therfore, not an immediate file system object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actully both of the commenters was right.
I did the following two things to fix the issue:

- In deed there was 2.0.0 and 2.0.3 versions in my classpath. I had to redownload everything with maven.
- According to mlk's comment I changed the encoding ot COSName.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING

Additionally I made a double check for every variable I try to write to the file, to prevent NULL parameters ad showText calls.